# Laravel - Is it a good practice to create other columns in pivot tables?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

So, i have a project on which the client can order food. The products are stored in a cart and then are inserted in a database. I want to design the Orders and Products tables but i also want to store the quantity and the subtotal price for each product.Orders and Products have N:N relation. Here are my table migrations:

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('product_id');
            $table->enum('status',['open','closed']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->float('price',8,2);
            $table->string('image_path');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

The pivot table:

```
Schema::create('order_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

The ways I see the solution are:

1. add the quantity and subtotal attributes to the pivot table( which i am not sure if it is good or bad)
2. insert rows for each of the specific product quantity (which will create a lot of rows for the same order and i'm not sure if this is good too).

Can you point me to a better solution? I am new to web development.

Comment: If your pivot table is being used for any data other than the linking references, then it ceases to be a pivot table and becomes a normal table

Comment: It's rare for it to be necessary. When two objects have permanence (a user and a location, for instance) a cross-reference table can hold data for the intersection (a particular user has an access level for a particular property). There's nothing in your example that has this requirement; the order can contain all the calculated financial data, or an invoice table can hold all that.